# Trying to get property 'title' of non-object al exportal excel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite

intento exportar un excel de mi index de una tabla, el problema viene cuando al darle al boton exportar me arroja el error

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

no se que tengo mal en mi codigo si pudieran ayudarme se los agradecería bastante!
aqui esta mi codigo de la vista

```
        <center> <h2>Menu Platillo</h2></center>
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead  class="thead-dark">
  <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Nombre del Platillo</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th>Descripcion</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Opciones</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach ($menu_platillo as $a1)
                <td>{{$a1->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$a1->nombre_platillo}}</td>
                <td>{{$a1->precio_platillo}}</td>
                <td>{{$a1->descripcion_platillo}}</td>
                <td>{{$a1->fecha}}</td>
                @endforeach
                <td><a href="{{URL::action('MenuPlatilloController@eliminar',['id'=>$a1->id])}}"><img src="img/eliminar.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <a href="{{URL::action('MenuPlatilloController@edit',['id'=>$a1->id])}}"><img src="img/editar.png" width="30" height="30"></a>

    </tr>

    </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      <th>Descargar Excel</th>
      <td><a href="{{URL::action('ExcelController@menuplatillos_excel')}}">descarga excel</a><br>
```

ruta

> ```
> Route::get('/export-menuplatillos','ExcelController@menuplatillos_excel');
> ```

controlador

```
public function menuplatillos_excel(Request $request){


    ob_start();
    Excel::create('MenuPlatillo', function($excel) use ($request){
                // nombre del archivo a descargar
        $excel->sheet('MenuPlatillo', function($sheet) use ($request){
            $sheet->row(1,['ID','Nombre del Platillo','Precio','Descripcion']);


            $menu_platillo=DB::SELECT('select * from menu_platillos');

            foreach ($menu_platillo as $index => $a1) {

                $sheet->row($index+1,
                    [$menu_platillo->id, $menu_platillo->nombre_platillo, $menu_platillo->precio_platillo, $menu_platillo->descripcion_platillo,
                    $menu_platillo->fecha]);
            }

        });

})->export('xls');
ob_end_clean();
```

}

anteriormente ya habia trabajado con maatwebsite pero me arrojaba el mismo error asi que tuve que usar datatables, pero para este proyecto es necesario usar esta libreria para los excel´s

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo tenés en el `foreach ($menu_platillo as $index => $a1)` del controlador.

Dentro del loop tenés que hacer referencia a `$a1`, que es un objeto que representa *un* platillo. Vos estás haciendo referencia a `$menu_platillo`, que es el array que contiene *todos* los platillos.

```
foreach ($menu_platillo as $index => $a1) {
    $sheet->row(
        $index + 1,
        [
            $a1->id,
            $a1->nombre_platillo,
            $a1->precio_platillo,
            $a1->descripcion_platillo,
            $a1->fecha,
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: lo e hecho, y al darle al boton de descarga de excel me redirige a la ruta del del excel mas no descarga nada :(

Comment: @JoseAndresSanchezMendoza no se como funciona lo que estás utilizando para generar el Excel. Podrías pasarme un link a la documentación? El `export` se supone que genera un xls? Probá hacer un return de eso. Y sino acá está la documentación para generar descargas: [link](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/responses#file-downloads).